# warning : is defined but never used

Tags: reactjs

I created a jsxUses.js file in the components folder, but when I import it in App.js its shows warning: 'jsxUses' is defined but never used

```
//This is App.js file
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import jsxuses from './components/jsxUses';
class App extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <jsxuses/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is jsxUses.js file

```
import React from 'react'

const jsxuses = () => {
    return (
        <div>     
            <h1> Hey there!</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
export default jsxuses;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Element should be `PascalCased`. So it should be

```
import JsxUses from './components/jsxUses';

...

<JsxUses />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jsxUses.js as:

```
...
const JsxUses = () => {
...
export default JsxUses;
```

And your App.js as:

```
import JsxUses from './components/jsxUses';
...
<JsxUses />
```

React file structure naming is unopinionated but React elements should be PascalCase for React to know whether or not you're using a function, class or an HTMLelementPascalCased. 
Look for more here: [Is there an official style guide or naming convention for React based projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221433/is-there-an-official-style-guide-or-naming-convention-for-react-based-projects)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should avoid using small latter for custom tags.

so you should do

```
 const JsxUses = () => {
 ...
 }
 export default JsxUses
```

and

```
import JsxUses from './components/jsxUses';
```

or if you want to write like -

```
const jsxuses = () => {
...
}
export default jsxuses
```

then you should import it like

```
import { default as JsxUses } from './components/jsxUses'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Use `import JsxUses from './components/JsxUses'; React component name should be PascalCase.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).